# How to use Javascript Arquero in browser

Tags: javascript, arquero

I am fairly new to the `JavaScript` world so please bear with me. I have come across the `JavaScript` library `Arquero` which I would like to use in a standalone html file. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/uwdata/arquero), it seems like it should be possible. They give a short example code (see below), which is intended to be used in Node.js environment (at least that is how I understood it), but I am unable to reproduce this in browser. How should I construct this script in a plain html?

```
// <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/arquero@latest"></script> // this is to reference the Arquero library

import { all, desc, op, table } from 'arquero';

// Average hours of sunshine per month, from https://usclimatedata.com/.
const dt = table({
  'Seattle': [69,108,178,207,253,268,312,281,221,142,72,52],
  'Chicago': [135,136,187,215,281,311,318,283,226,193,113,106],
  'San Francisco': [165,182,251,281,314,330,300,272,267,243,189,156]
});

// Sorted differences between Seattle and Chicago.
// Table expressions use arrow function syntax.
dt.derive({
    month: d => op.row_number(),
    diff:  d => d.Seattle - d.Chicago
  })
  .select('month', 'diff')
  .orderby(desc('diff'))
  .print();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs specify:

> Arquero will be imported into the `aq` global object

So to make use of the functions you need to prefix them with `aq`.

```js
// Average hours of sunshine per month, from https://usclimatedata.com/.
const dt = aq.table({
  'Seattle': [69,108,178,207,253,268,312,281,221,142,72,52],
  'Chicago': [135,136,187,215,281,311,318,283,226,193,113,106],
  'San Francisco': [165,182,251,281,314,330,300,272,267,243,189,156]
});

// Sorted differences between Seattle and Chicago.
// Table expressions use arrow function syntax.
dt.derive({
    month: d => aq.op.row_number(),
    diff:  d => d.Seattle - d.Chicago
  })
  .select('month', 'diff')
  .orderby(aq.desc('diff'))
  .print();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/arquero@latest"></script>
```